# get html element in react tests using enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

How to get HTML elements in react tests with Enzyme? I am able to find wrappers. But I want HTML element. Becuase block of my code which needs to be covered has offsetParent check on HTML element which is not getting covered. Below is the sample.

```
 it('add class test', async () => {

    const wrapper = mount((
        <div class='ag-cell'>
            <div class='ag-react-conatiner'></div>
            <span anum={3} abool={false} />
            <span anum="3" abool="false" />
        </div>
    ));

    const x = wrapper.find('.ag-react-conatiner').offsetParent;

    console.log(wrapper.find('.ag-react-conatiner').offsetParent);
 }
```

I am able to get wrapper.find('.ag-react-conatiner'). How i can get offsetParent of it?

Answer (score 1):

Why not add the attribute data-testid='something' to your elements 
use

```
const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
expect(wrapper.find('[data-testid="something"]')).to.have.lengthOf(1);
```

Using the above attribute makes it clear its used for testing , unlike classes which can easily be renamed etc in development.

Comment: Problem is not about finding wrapper. With out data-testid also i could get proper wrapper output. But in my case i need to get offsetParent of HTMLElement which i can't find on wrapper object

Comment: As wrapper.find('.ag-react-conatiner') is not HTML element i can't find offsetParent on it. I need a way to get HTML element from corresponding wrappers.

Comment: Does this help const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
expect(wrapper.find(Foo).closest('.bar')).to.have.lengthOf(1);

Comment: Shallow won't help. I have tested it. Shallow only render s single level.

Comment: and you cannot use mount , I only though find().closest might help. When you say offsetParent check  can you show me the code ? I'm not sure I fully understood